# What to do with moss on rock?

Tags: landscaping, moss, rocks, rock-gardening

I have several rocks like this with moss growing. They are quite old. Frankly we don't like moss

[image]

What to do with this?

Some options I am thinking:

1. Leave alone - Because removing will make it look uglier (lots of white spots).
2. Scrape using a knife then pressure wash
3. Just pressure wash

Any thought?

Comment: Yeah, rocks are "quite old" - even young earthers think they have been around for 6,000 years :)

Comment: You may be able to trade them for bare rocks , I think a custom landscaper would be interested. I believe landscapers get a premium for mossy rocks. I just bought ordinary rocks and grew my own moss.

Comment: The Japanese would consider this moss vastly valuable.  THIS moss as well as dove grayed wood is worth THOUSANDS.  One boulder, a bit bigger of course with moss, heck the moss is half of the value. has been purchased for 20K.  Japanese gardening principles are the most regarded on this planet.  Forget Buddha and Pagodas thingies in the garden.  Japanese make their gardens look as if no human had touched or interfered...

Comment: @stormy Because it is sunny everywhere in the world EXCEPT the Pacific Northwest. So I have moss on top of my head as well.

Comment: @alephzero  Most rocks are actually millions of years old.  There are a few resurfacing that are as old as our planet.  Is 'young earther' a thing?  Like...flat earth?

Comment: @HP I live in the PNW; Bellingham, Seattle, Bellevue, Auburn, Carnation and Duvall...That azalea and stone are breath taking beautiful.  If I were you I would think about getting Gro-Co from Sawdust Supply.  They will spray it on your beds and they do an incredible job.  I got spoiled with this stuff.  It is beautiful, fine textured, uniform, dark taupe. No sticks and chunks.  No pesticide residues and no weed seeds!  Keep it thin around the bottom of Azaleas and Rhododendrons other shallow rooted shrubs.  This FEEDS your soil beautifully, and you can forget weed problems.

Comment: You've obviously never walked on moss with bare feet if you don't like moss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start liking the mosses. Very nice and relaxing. And it make your garden have an "alpine look".

You may remove it (strong brush), or just turning them, but they will return quickly, unless you try to fight humidity: more sand and stones, less mulch, and maybe you should remove some trees (so having more sun). In such case you may have a more "rocky look" (dry).

Ev, you can plant some runner, which will cover the rocks (e.g. periwinkle), or you may plant some Sedum/Sempervivum/Saxifraga on the rock: they will look better, and they will take some humidity.

I fear it is a lost battle, if you doesn't take a lot of resources regularly.